# Why cannot MySQL Connector.NET correctly map types to C# types?

Tags: c#, mysql, powershell, mysql-connector

MySQL table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE `table` (
  `id` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'Auto-increment ID',
  `data_provider_id` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'Data provider ID',
  `is_active` bit(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT b'1' COMMENT '0 = retired source',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `DATA_PROVIDER_ID` (`data_provider_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=17 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

C# code:

```
public static class MySqlConnector
{
    public static DataTable QueryDatabase(
            MySqlConnection mysqlConnection,
            string mysqlQuery)
    {
        MySqlCommand mysqlCommand = new MySqlCommand(mysqlQuery, mysqlConnection);
        MySqlDataReader mysqlDataReader = mysqlCommand.ExecuteReader();

        DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
        dataTable.Load(mysqlDataReader);

        return dataTable;
    }
}
```

...

```
mysqlQuery = @"
    SELECT
      `id`,
      `data_provider_id`,
      `is_active`
    FROM
      `{0}`;
    ";
mysqlQuery = String.Format(mysqlQuery, tableName);
DataTable dt = MySqlConnector.QueryDatabase(mysqlConnection, mysqlQuery);
```

Now when I call `GetType()` on `dt` fields, it says that `id` is `Int32` (instead of `Byte`), `data_provider_id` is `Byte` (surprisingly correct) and `is_active` is `Uint64` (instead of `Boolean`).

It gets worse. I have another table where `id` field is `int(1) unsigned` and `QueryDatabase()` still returns it as a signed int.

---

PowerShell code for quick testing:

```
# Importing MySQL Connector.NET DLL.
$sMySqlServer = "server"
$sPath = "\\{0}\Connector.NET 6.9.7\Assemblies\v4.5\MySql.Data.dll" `
    -f $sMySqlServer
Add-Type -Path $sPath

# Creating MySQL connection.
$sMySqlUser = "user"
$sMySqlPassword = "password"
$sMySqlDatabase = "test"

$sMySqlConnectionString = "server={0};uid={1};pwd={2};database={3};" `
    -f $sMySqlServer, $sMySqlUser, $sMySqlPassword, $sMySqlDatabase
$oMySqlConnection = New-Object -TypeName MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection
$oMySqlConnection.ConnectionString = $sMySqlConnectionString
$oMySqlConnection.Open()

# Getting raw data.
$sMySqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM `table` ;"
$oMySqlCommand = New-Object -TypeName `
    MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand($sMySqlQuery, $oMySqlConnection)
$oMySqlDataReader = $oMySqlCommand.ExecuteReader()
$oDataTable = New-Object -TypeName System.Data.DataTable
$oDataTable.Load($oMySqlDataReader)

$oDataTable | Get-Member
```

Output:

```
   TypeName: System.Data.DataRow

Name              MemberType            Definition                                        
----              ----------            ----------                                        
AcceptChanges     Method                void AcceptChanges()                              
BeginEdit         Method                void BeginEdit()                                  
CancelEdit        Method                void CancelEdit()                                 
ClearErrors       Method                void ClearErrors()                                
Delete            Method                void Delete()                                     
EndEdit           Method                void EndEdit()                                    
Equals            Method                bool Equals(System.Object obj)                    
GetChildRows      Method                System.Data.DataRow[] GetChildRows(string relat...
GetColumnError    Method                string GetColumnError(int columnIndex), string ...
GetColumnsInError Method                System.Data.DataColumn[] GetColumnsInError()      
GetHashCode       Method                int GetHashCode()                                 
GetParentRow      Method                System.Data.DataRow GetParentRow(string relatio...
GetParentRows     Method                System.Data.DataRow[] GetParentRows(string rela...
GetType           Method                type GetType()                                    
HasVersion        Method                bool HasVersion(System.Data.DataRowVersion vers...
IsNull            Method                bool IsNull(int columnIndex), bool IsNull(strin...
RejectChanges     Method                void RejectChanges()                              
SetAdded          Method                void SetAdded()                                   
SetColumnError    Method                void SetColumnError(int columnIndex, string err...
SetModified       Method                void SetModified()                                
SetParentRow      Method                void SetParentRow(System.Data.DataRow parentRow...
ToString          Method                string ToString()                                 
Item              ParameterizedProperty System.Object Item(int columnIndex) {get;set;},...
data_provider_id  Property              byte data_provider_id {get;set;}                  
id                Property              int id {get;set;}                                 
is_active         Property              uint64 is_active {get;set;}
```

SSDD

---

[Solved] Even though wchiquito's answer isn't a complete solution, it nudged me in the right direction. Type translation in `DataTable.Load()` is indeed somewhat broken so you need to add basic schema to your DataTable before calling `Load()`. The following is probably not perfect but it worked for me:

```
private static void TranslateSchema(
        DataTable dataTable,
        MySqlDataReader mysqlDataReader)
{
    string columnName;
    Type columnType;

    mysqlDataReader.Read();

    for (int i = 0; i < mysqlDataReader.FieldCount; i++)
    {
        columnName = mysqlDataReader.GetName(i);
        columnType = mysqlDataReader.GetFieldType(i);

        dataTable.Columns.Add(columnName, columnType);
    }
}
```

`bit(1)` still becomes `UInt64` but this I can live with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of Connector/Net is using? With version 6.9.7 I can't reproduce the problem.

MySQL:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `table` (
    `id` TINYINT(1) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'Auto-increment ID',
    `data_provider_id` TINYINT(1) UNSIGNED NOT NULL COMMENT 'Data provider ID',
    `is_active` BIT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT b'1' COMMENT '0 = retired source',
    `id_temp` INT(1) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    KEY `DATA_PROVIDER_ID` (`data_provider_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

C#:

```c#
...
DataTable schema = dr.GetSchemaTable();
...
```

Result:

```
`id`               -> System.Byte
`data_provider_id` -> System.Byte
`is_active`        -> System.UInt64
`id_temp`          -> System.UInt32
```

[6.2.3.1 Collections](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-programming-getschema-collections.html)

```
...
DataTable table = mysqlConnection.GetSchema("DataTypes");
...
```

Result:

```
TypeName = BIT
...
CreateFormat = BIT
... 
DataType = System.UInt64
...
============================
TypeName = TINY INT
...
CreateFormat = TINYINT UNSIGNED
...
DataType = System.Byte
...
============================
TypeName = INT
...
CreateFormat = INT UNSIGNED
...
DataType = System.UInt32
...
```

Comment: Many thanks for your reply! I really appreciate any input. Unfortunately, I can reproduce the issue in C# and PowerShell (2.0 and 3.0) on three different machines. Upgrading to Connector 6.9.7 doesn't help at all. Admittedly I didn't try `GetSchema()` because I don't care what it says. All I care about is actual types `QueryDatabase()` populates my datatable with.